# How to auto send messages from a Telegram Group to my server?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

My need is to send ALL messages from a telgram Group to my PHP server. I suppose that I have to use a bot and attach it to my Telegram group. My question is : how to set this bot to send all messages that group members post on my PHP server?
I google for a while but did'nt find exactly what I want to do...
Thks !

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your bot to the group, from which You want to resend messages. Next, you set webhook on the page where you want to receive messages or use getUpdate instead. It will send you associative array with first [key] message if it's manual input, or [callback_query] if it's inline button, for example.